# Node js with apache or nginx?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I want to use apache/nginx to load static content and use php then use node js to do some real-time application in the same page, Which one is the better choice to combine with?

Answer (score 1):

Both will do fine. Anything other than that will veer into opinion.

Saying that here's my (brief) opinion:

Apache has been round longer and to some it's more established, with more features and support. Any new module or software you want will almost certainly work with Apache. To others it's staid and stuck in the past.

Nginx is quicker (though honestly you'll struggle to see the difference except for very high volume sites) and has quickly become the web server of choice for a lot of people if you don't have any specific need for Apache for your code. So a lot more newer projects seem to choose Nginx.

Ultimately both with allow proxying to Node so either will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP just to load the stuff from the database for Node, I strongly recommend to instead use the [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module for Node.js. I installed it and wrote all the code my project needed in about an hour. You simply make all the queries from inside Node, which is awesome.

As for the server, I use Apache (XAMPP) and it works perfectly.